# Python: Schedule job to run between two predefined times

Tags: python

I am trying to get a command to be executed between two predefined times;

Here is what I have so far

```
##Time
day_of_week = datetime.date.today().weekday() # 0 is Monday, 6 is Sunday
time = datetime.datetime.now().time()

if day_of_week < 5 and (time > datetime.time(17) and time < datetime.time(5)):  
    print "True"
```

It seems to execute after 1700 just fine but once the time rolls over to the next day, past 0000 it doesn’t run at all.
Any help would be much appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Perhaps something like crontab/taskscheduler or this?: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

Comment: I plan on using cron to execute the script hourly but i need to be able to parse a log file and if the time stamp is between these two times run a command

Comment: "I plan on using cron..." notice that in this case it will run twice per day, once before 5 and once after 17. Is that what you intend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time > datetime.time(17) and time < datetime.time(5)
```

How can something be more than 17 and less than 5?

Perhaps:

```
if ((day_of_week < 5 and time > datetime.time(17)) or
    (0 < day_of_the_week < 6 and time < datetime.time(5))):
```

Comment: I agree, i just couldnt figure out how to write it.

Comment: Why did you change the format though on the second half?
I was able to successfully run using this format.
if (day_of_week < 5 and time > datetime.time(17)) or (day_of_week < 5 and time < datetime.time(12)):

But using (0 < day_of_week < 6 ) it wouldnt run due to your excluding monday correct?

Comment: @user3723008, did you want it to run Monday mornings? I figured you wanted every weekday night from 17-05, which means Monday 00-05 is out but Saturday 00-05 is in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your condition `(time > datetime.time(17) and time < datetime.time(5))`. `time` cannot have an hour > 17 and < 5 at the same time.

It may help to think this through step by step:

```
    ##Time
    from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

    # when to run the job
    time_of_day_min = time(17)
    time_of_day_max = time(5)
    weekdays_min = [0,1,2,3,4] # run Mon-Fri after 17.00
    weekdays_max = [1,2,3,4,5] # run Tue-Sat before 05.00

    # current day and time
    day_of_week = date.today().weekday() # 0 is Monday, 6 is Sunday
    now_time = datetime.now()

    # figure out if it runs between 17.00 - 23.59, or 00.00 - 05.00
    run_before_midnight = now_time >= time_of_day_min 
    run_after_midnight = now_time <= time_of_day_max

    # check if conditions are met. Note the *or*
    if (day_of_week in weekdays_min and run_before_midnight) or \
       (day_of_week in weekdays_max and run_after_midnight):
        print "Running!"
```